# How to access Individual Microphone from Microphone Array(Win 8.1)

Tags: wasapi

I want to access individual microphone in mic array, for testing quality purpose.
How can I access that using c# ? 
Can I use NAudio for it ? How can i use WASAPI for it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how the mic array is implemented.  Many hardware vendors do the array processing on-chip, and only present Windows with the post-processed audio.  Other vendors let Windows do the array processing.

You can tell whether a device is a microphone array by looking at the part subtype of the device; microphone arrays have a subtype of KSNODETYPE_MICROPHONE_ARRAY.

I'm not that familiar with NAudio, but if it exposes IKsControl and IDeviceTopology, you should be able to get it to work.  (I have some samples in C++, but not in C#.)